# Nodejs local website, working from 127.0.0.1, but doesnt load css/js when other device access it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a simple web app that I am using to control a device, its just html+css+js.

I want to host that app on a raspberry pi and use it as a local server, so that I can open that app from tablets, pcs, phones etc, whatever I want.

I tried setting up a nodejs server to host the app, this is the code that I used, found it somewhere here on the forum:

```
var http = require('http');
var fileSystem = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp){
    fileSystem.readFile('./index.html', function(error, fileContent){
        if(error){
            resp.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            resp.end('Error');
        }
        else{
            resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            resp.write(fileContent);
            resp.end();
        }
    });
});

server.listen(8081);    
console.log('listening');
```

And it is kinda working. If I open the app from http://127.0.0.1:8081 on the computer on which it is hosted (mind you atm I am not on the raspberry, still testing on my personal pc) it is working as expected, if I directly open the index.html it is also working just fine.
But if I go and try to open it from my phone, or from my laptop from http://192.168.0.2:8081 it is not working. By not working I mean the following:

- On the laptop it just renders the bare html and nothing else, there are several errors in the console about 'unexpected token <' I have one for each of my javascript files, and it is pointing at the first row of my HTML file the  row
- On my phone, same issue, I connected it for USB debugging to chrome to see the Console, I have the same errors screenshot: http://prntscr.com/s65x0t

Here is my HTML code, I did some research, many people were pointing out that some of the JS files that I have linked in my HTML may have incorrect directory or file name, but at least I dont see an issue there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/easy-numpad.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-modal.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Model.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/UI.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/config.js"></script>
  <link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  <link href="./css/easy-numpad.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Did You Serve Assets of HTML in Node Js?
You Can Server Static Content in Node js With the following code:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  resp.writeHead(404);
  resp.end(JSON.stringify(err));
  return;
}
resp.writeHead(200);
resp.end(data);
});
```

Replace this and use `http://192.168.x.x/index.html` to open your html file and html file call for assets.
maybe require to remove `.` from address of assets files
(for example 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>` convert to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>`)

Answer (score 0):

All requests to your server will return the `index`-html page which is why you see the `Syntax Error`/`Mime-Type warning` when Chrome tries to load the `js/css` files.

The solution is to set up additional routes/handling for other html, javascript and css files.

However, I recommend using `express` and just serving the content [statically](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), as express takes care of this automatically:

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8081;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

With that just create a directory called `public` in the same directory as the server.js and all static content will be served automatically from there, e.g.

```
- your-server-app
 -- server.js
 -- public
 --- index.html
 --- js
 ---- test.js
```

and an example for the index.html page:

```
<html>
  <script src="js/test.js"></script>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello from Index page</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, actually I did stumble upon express 30 mins ago and did it pretty much the same as you suggested, but I redid it to your exact code. It is working, but not entirely. From 127.0.0.1:8081 again everything works just fine, from my laptop when I do the 192.168.0.2:8081 everything loads, but my javascript is not working properly. I have a config.js file and model.js, the config.js contains information about the IP of the device (which for some reason is null when i check in the browser!) and model.getdata and model.setdata depend on that config.url parameter, which they can not read

Comment: Even if I manually try to set config.URL = '.....' in the console and then invoke the get/setdata functions, they still dont see it and attempt to request data from http://null/....
That issue is not present if I open 127.0.0.1:8081 on the local PC where it is all hosted

Comment: Well, this is most probably a separate issue as it has nothing to do with serving the content, pls open a new one and include the contents of the scripts...